# When I add the import for mParticle_appboy I get a "No such Module" error

Tags: ios, appboy

I've created a new iOS project and I'm using cocoa pods to manage dependencies.  When I try to us the dependency for mParticle_appboy I get the error "No such module 'mParticle_Appboy'.   But I do can see that that dependency is in my pods.
[image]

This is what my pod file looks like,
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

```
target 'testbraze' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!


  # Pods for testbraze
  pod 'mParticle-Appboy', '~> 8.0'

  target 'testbrazeTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
end

   target 'testbrazeUITests' do
# Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I am opening the project using the .xcworspace file.  I've tried pod reintegrate and pod install, as well as the Xcode option to clean the build.  Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: You say that the error is No such module **'mParicle_Appboy'** - you have no 't' - is this a typo in your question or your import statement?

Comment: @Paulw11 that was a typo in the question.

Comment: According to the [quickstart](https://github.com/mParticle/mparticle-apple-sdk#swift) the required import is `import mParticle_Apple_SDK`

Comment: I get the same error with the `import mParticle_Apple_SDK ` import.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `import mParticle_Apple_SDK` as shown in the [quickstart](https://github.com/mParticle/mparticle-apple-sdk#swift)

Unless you have other dependencies that require Cocoapods, I would suggest that you use Swift Package Manager.

Comment: I get the same error with that import.   Both should be available from the `mParticle-Appboy` dependency. 

This is a demo/learning project for me.  I've been unable to solve an issue with braze popups at work and this project is me trying to learn how the damn dependencies on iOS work.   (new iOS dev). So I need to learn how Cocoapods works.   Though I'd love it if you educated me on why Swift package Manager is better.

Comment: Swift package manager is better because it is built right in to Xcode.  There is no need to install external tools or do anything from the command line. Cocoapods predates any form on in-built dependency manager in Xcode.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm. not sure.  I created a new project, ran `pod init` added `pod 'mParticle-Appboy', '~> 8.0'` to the pod file and ran `pod install`.  I then opened the xcworkspace and I was able to `import mParticle_Apple_SDK` and build.